# C++ vscode extension make the OS extremely slow

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not sure whether here is the right place to ask this. Anyway,
when I activate C/C++ Microsoft extension of vscode, after a while the OS become extremely slow, and again back to normal state after few minuets. `htop` does not show any CPU usage and there is enough free RAM. I am sure it is because of the extension. I have check this on Mint 18.3 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I an using :

```
vscode 1.32.3
Commit: a3db5be9b5c6ba46bb7555ec5d60178ecc2eaae4
Date: 2019-03-14T23:38:49.842Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-20-generic
```

Is this a bug in the extension or what?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug or something like that in the extension. Because I use it everyday and it works just fine and there is no problem like what you said.
Maybe it is because of the compiler you have on your system. Which compiler have you installed on your OS? I'll be glad if I can help you with this.

Comment: I use g++, .vscode folder is 1.4GB, I did not install new comiler, just default preinstalled ones on ubuntu